# How to paste a block of text in IntelliJ+Python plugin in a string?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I have a block of text that I would like to put in a string. When I paste the text, I get:

```
hello = "This paragraph forms
a block of text, which
can be short like this,
or extremely long!"
```

Which is wrong in Python. Is there any tricks? I am using IntelliJ 2016.02 Community with the Python plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With newline:**

```
>>> hello = '''
... This paragraph forms
... a block of text, which
... can be short like this,
... or extremely long!'''
>>> print(hello)

This paragraph forms
a block of text, which
can be short like this,
or extremely long!
>>>
```

**Without newline:**

```
>>> hello = (
... "This paragraph forms "
... "a block of text, which "
... "can be short like this, "
... "or extremely long!"
... )
>>> print(hello)
This paragraph forms a block of text, which can be short like this, or extremely long!
>>>
```